# What does POPs mean here?

Tags: meaning, terminology, initialisms

I am reading a post about network, I don't know what "POPs" mean here:

> Our big, global, managed DNS network — the one most of our customers use — is spread across six continents and 17 **POPs** (with some more on the way).

Is that a region or something like that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PoP in the context of DNS means "Point of Presence".  Anything beyond that is a computer tech question, not an English usage question. Good luck.

Here's an article that mentions PoPs  (and SuperPoPs!) 
http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/dns-made-easy-expands-network-infrastructure-in-hong-kong/

Answer (score 5):

In networking, POP means [Point Of Presence](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/1704/point-of-presence-pop). Another one is **Post Office Protocol**.

> **Point of presence (POP)** is the point at which two or more different
> networks or communication devices build a connection with each other.

**POP** is primarily the **infrastructure** **that allows remote users connect to** the Internet.

POP mainly refers to an access point, location or facility that connects to and helps other devices establish a connection with the Internet.

> **Post Office Protocol** **(POP)** is used to retrieve e-mail from a mail server.
> Most e-mail applications use this protocol.

So, here **POP** means Point Of Presence.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, POP would refer to Point of Presence, as noted in other answers.

More specifically, a POP is a physical location where servers are located.

Generally this is within a Data Centre, and most of the time it refers to dedicated hardware such as a leased server.  Services with smaller requirements might be able to use a VPS as a POP, using something like Amazon Web Services or Digital Ocean as the supplier.

The exact placement depends on what your goal is, but normally companies try to place their servers very close to high bandwidth users and in a number of different countries.

If I had a DNS service running on servers in New York, London and Tokyo then I might refer to that as 3 POPs.
In such a case I would be placing them far apart to prevent any single failure from taking down more than one POP, and also to get DNS replies to the customer faster due to being physically closer to the servers.